# Android ListView items reappering

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, listitem

I'm working on a ListView based app and I have a very weird problem, my ListItems are reappering and the correct item is not shown in the correct spot. For the sake of making this easy to understand I've set the text on each ListItem to be the same as it's position. I'm doing this in my adapters getView() call. If I have my Nexus 7 4 ListItems are visible. If I have a total of 10 ListItems then it will go like 0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. This goes for all devices meaining that the number of items initially on screen + 1 will be correct while all other ListItems are rearrenged.

In which part of my code do you guys think my problem lies because right now I've been trying to fix this for hours and I'm clueless. All help is very much appreciated.

EDIT:

Here's my getView():

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CountdownItem ci = mTitle.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        holder = new CountdownViewHolder();
        holder.mTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textPrim);
        holder.mSubtitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textSec);
        holder.mDayProgress = (ProgressBar) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.day_progress);
        holder.mMonthProgress = (ProgressBar) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.month_progress);
        holder.mYearText = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.year_text);
        holder.day_help = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.day_help);
        holder.month_help = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.month_help);

        holder.setTitle(Integer.toString(position) + " Title");
        holder.setSubtitle(ci.getSubtitle());
        holder.fixImageAndText(position);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (CountdownViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Post the code of your `getView()` method. A ListAdapter recycles views and maybe you aren't taking this properly into consideration.

Comment: @DavidWasser My getView() has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the ViewHolder pattern correctly. The following code needs to be moved outside the `if/else` clause and before `return convertView`:

```
   holder.setTitle(Integer.toString(position) + " Title");
   holder.setSubtitle(ci.getSubtitle());
   holder.fixImageAndText(position);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is because android reuses views in lists, to increment performance and rendering speed.

The holder pattern is used to store views ids. After you retrieve them, you have to set the text you want to see inside.

For example, you retrieve your data (e.g. `myDataArray[position]`), and if it's all ok, you proceed setting title, subtitle, dayprogress, etc. with TextView's `setText()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct behaviour for the listview when it is reusing cells, the problem is that you only set the values when the cell is first created.

When convertView == null the listview has no cell to recycle. However, once it has created a few it can reuse them to display as you scroll.

What you need to do is set the title and subtitle even when convertView is not null. That way you're setting them for each new list position.